# Can't get rid of ErrorProvider message in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, error-handling, errorprovider

I'm starting with c# as my second language and i'm doing a windows form app (.NET framework) with ms sql server db.
I tried to erase an ErrorProvider (called ErrorProvider1) for the FirstName column after a quick test. However, it keeps popping up every time I insert a new row in DB even after deleting.
I erased all the code related to it and also de ErrorProvider component in Dashboard.cs [Design]. It's not interfering with my Save method, but it's really annoying.

Any thoughts on that?
Thanks for the help.

[ErrorProvider message after delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBo4V.jpg)

[Not interfering with my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyOUI.jpg)

Comment: check wired events?

Comment: You mean my events for the btnSave where Validating was wired with errorprovider? Its empty

Comment: Found the error... I didn't erase all the code.
            if (ValidateChildren(ValidationConstraints.Enabled))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(txtFirstName.Text, "First Name can't be blank!");
            }

Thanks anyway!

Comment: If it was helpfull, please accept an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check wired events.
Probably you got your button's function call in some event wired.